# Openshift tomcat, unable to find server.xml and context.xml?

Tags: tomcat, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have installed my app on openshift tomcat.

I wanted to setup auto redirect from http to https. However i am unable to find server.xml and context.xml at place where it is supposed to be.

[https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openshift/getting-started#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https)

I ssh to box also, but could not find context/server xml there as well.

I am confused on how to proceed? Should i define my own xml files in my git repo? or define manually on box by sshing to it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.

Once app is created, i need to use .openshift in the default git repo created.

So i have to merge my project with openshift git repo.